# unable to install composer for symfony

Tags: symfony, composer-php, windows-firewall

I am using a computer provided by my work org and I do not have any access to change firewall since I am just a user.

I am trying to install Composer to start on a symfony 2 project. When I try Composer exe file to install, I see this message - `The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy`

I Googled it but the solutions all given are related to firewall and can be solved by an Admin only.

Comment: Composer internally uses PHP to download everything. AFAIK PHP 5.5 had an issue with resolving certificates at some point. Can you run `<?php file_get_contents('https://github.com/') ?>` and tell us if it triggers any errors?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you have network issues: `Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy`. You probably might want to work this out but since you have no access to network settings then it will be easier just to use `Manual Download` option from https://getcomposer.org/download/ . Just download `composer.phar` file from [this](https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar) url

Comment: `certificate verify failed` is the problem, not the network issue.